# Material UI Progress Indicator center align horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Stack: Meteor + React + Material UI

Here's the full code of my 'main' renderer components:

```js
// Sorry for not giving material-UI CSS,
// cause it cannot be served as a stand-alone CSS

render() {
    return ( 
      <div className = "container">
        <AppBar title = "test" />
        <Tabs /> // Tab contents goes here
        <RefreshIndicator
          left={70} // Required properties
          top={0}  // Required properties
          status="loading"
          style={{ 
              display: 'inline-block',
              position: 'relative',
              margin: '0 auto' }} />
      </div>
   );
},
```

I want to make the Refresh Indicator horizontally center aligned beneath of myTabs like this whirling circle in this picture :

[image]

In the document of Material UI [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-progress/), this indicator comes with following styles:

```
display: 'inline-block',
position: 'relative',
```

With this styles I cant align it center horizontally, and without this styles, I can`t even locate it where I wanted.

What I have tried :

1. margin: 0 auto --> failed
2. text-align: center --> failed
3. display: flex --> failed
4. combination of 1 & 2 --> failed
5. left={$(window).width/2-20} -->  This works but I'd like to use CSS only

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle or jsbin to show the problem? Can you try removing the `position: 'relative'` and check?

Comment: I'd suggest wrapping the Refresh Indicator component in a div that's been classed with flex. Then center it with `justify-content:center`.

Comment: @Adiya Singh Sorry, but it seems that there is no way of creating stand alone material-UI example on a jsfiddle/jsbin... Material-UI only has NPM installation this time.

Comment: @lux I did like

`<div sytle={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}><RefreshIndicator left={70} top={0} status="loading"
        style={{ display: 'inline-block', position: 'relative', margin: '0 auto' }}/>
        </div>`
but failed.

Comment: It's rather annoying how flex doesn't work with this indicator out of the box.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is how I did to ensure it's horizontally centered. Works great for me.

1. Set the parent component style to  `position: 'relative'`.
2. Set the refresh indicator style to `marginLeft: '50%'`, and `left={-20}` (assuming the size is 40).

here is the code (I put it in a CardText component).

```
    ...
    <CardText style={{position: 'relative'}}>
      <RefreshIndicator
        size={40}
        left={-20}
        top={10}
        status={'loading'}
        style={{marginLeft: '50%'}}
      />
    </CardText>
    ...
```

Comment: This does not center the progress indicator completely, the progress indicator gets offset from the center with this solution.

Comment: Rather than rely on `left: -20` and knowing "because it's 40 pixels wide" you can utilize `transform: translateX(-50%)` and have it be responsive.

Answer (score 35):

The solution below centres progress indicator without any hacky calculations that cause element to be offset:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
   <RefreshIndicator status="loading" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'd argue this is the preferred display method over `position: absolute` - TMU it may be a bigger "performance" issue with lots of `position: absolute/relative` elements on a page, but this method will center it _no matter the container_ versus the accepted answer that required you to know the width.

Answer (score 11):

In **Material UI v5**, there is a [`Stack`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/) component which serves as a flexbox container. By default the direction is `column`, to center it horizontally you can set `alignItems` to `center`:

```
<Stack alignItems="center">
  <CircularProgress />
</Stack>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: I like this answer. I added margins: ```<Stack alignItems="center" spacing={5}>
  <CircularProgress />
</Stack>```.

Answer (score 2):

circularprocess in material ui and text middle of page stackoverflow

```
 <div style={{ alignItems: "center", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}>
                                <CircularProgress />
                                <span style={{ justifyContent: "center", position: "fixed", top: "55%" }}>Loading...please wait</span>
                            </div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Backdrop Component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-backdrop/) will place the progress indicator in the center and also can add a dimmed layer over your application. This component is available with MUI V5.

```
<Backdrop open={enabled} sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}><CircularProgress color="secondary" /></Backdrop>
```